# Append data using update method to json object just add last loop item using python

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to learn `python`

My version is `3.8`

It's a simple task:

1. I read a REST API
2. Get a JSON response
3. parse JSON response
4. Filter response

And now I want to add objects bigger than a specific date to a variable.

**This is my response scheme:**

```
"2020-04-30":
{
    "total_cases":83944
    "deaths":4637
    "recovered":78493
    "critical":41
    "tested":0
    "death_ratio":0.05523920709044124
    "recovery_ratio":0.9350638520918708
}
"2020-04-29":
{
    "total_cases":83940
    "deaths":4637
    "recovered":78455
    "critical":50
    "tested":0
    "death_ratio":0.05524183940910174
    "recovery_ratio":0.9346557064569931
}
...
...
```

**And this is my Code:**

```
start_time = "2020-04-15"
since = datetime.strptime(start_time, "%Y-%m-%d")

plot_material = {}
plot_material['ch'] = china['data'][start_time]
tmp_counter = 0

for date in china['data']:
    tmp_date = datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d")
    if (tmp_date < since):
        tmp_counter += 1
        plot_material['ch'].update(china['data'][date])

print(json.dumps(plot_material, indent=4)) #just add the last element
```

Theres just last element appear in `plot_material['ch']` and it seems values are overwritten repeatedly!

***Do You Have any Idea where's my mistake?***

***Thanks in Advance***

Comment: Are you trying to get a list of all dates less than `since` or you just want to get the smallest one?

Comment: @MoosaSaadat I'm trying to get `all` dates. I tried `.append()` either but there's error with dict...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`update()` is used to update the dictionary. If your dictionary already has a value for the specified key, it will get overwritten. Otherwise, a new **key/value** pair will be added.

Here you want to create a list of all dates less than `since`. So, you need to have a `list` for `ch` key in your dictionary:

```py
plot_material = {}
# Notice the square brackets
plot_material['ch'] = [china['data'][start_time]]
```

And, then you will just `.append()` the new values:

```py
plot_material['ch'].append(china['data'][date])
```